# Visual studio 2015 Update 2, TeamExplorer: where is the exclude option?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Yesterday I updated to VS 2015 Update 2! I noticed the possibility to stage files in the TeamExplorer (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx).

[image: The new stage option]

But why is the option "Exclude from change" gone? At least, i cannot find it anymore! I find this very anoying because I used this a lot for committing just one file! How can I commit just one file in the new VS 2015 update 2? Maybe i am overseeing something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can stage your one file and then CommitAll button will be changed to CommitStaged.
So now if you have to commit one of 7 files you don't need to exclude 6 other, but you have to stage just one.

Comment: Ahh, yes. I now understand. I was confused because staging in TFS works in another way.Thanks!

Comment: What just happened is that the unstage/stage terminology aligns better with Git than TFS's Exclude/Include. This change was surprising at first, but if someone comes from pure Git background and no TFS knowledge, and they start to hop on VS, they will be familiar with this.

Comment: OK, but what if want to commit 6 of 7 files?

Comment: @romanoza, so you have to click StageAll button ([screenshot](http://joxi.ru/wRmzlMZTQnGVAO))
And then unstage 1 of your 7 files

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, Visual Studio now is closer to the git workflow. As such, the separate exclude option is gone, but the stage area respects the settings in the .gitignore file.

So instead of using Visual Studio's exclude option, use git's .gitignore file to exclude files and directories. Additionally this will mean that other git tools also respect the ignored/excluded files.

See here for a documentation of the .gitignore file:
https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore